# What changes do I have to make to a .NET 2.0 Application so that it installs and runs fine on Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-2.0, installation

I get  CLR20r3 error and very non-descriptive messages.

I tried making an installer as well as used click once to deploy the app onto the server but failed both the times. Is there a set of steps that we have to go through to target 2008 server deployments?

Here is the error message :
Description:

Stopped working

Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:                      CLR20r3
 Problem Signature 01:                     my App Name 
 Problem Signature 02:                     1.0.0.0
 Problem Signature 03:                     4b7b2b38
 Problem Signature 04:                     my App Name 
 Problem Signature 05:                     1.0.0.0
 Problem Signature 06:                     4b7b2b38
 Problem Signature 07:                     d
 Problem Signature 08:                     e0
 Problem Signature 09:                     System.InvalidOperationException

OS Version:                                        6.1.7600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:                                            1033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a check for compatibility option when i right clicked on the application (on the server).

I selected that and it came up with a suggestion that I should pick xp settings. I selected the option and every thing worked.

I still dont have a clear answer on why it didnot work with out any of the changes. I am going to debug the app using windows 7 machine and woudl post any findings worth mentioning.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have to make no changes.

The first thing I would do is just copy the bin\debug to a server and see if it runs.

You may be having platform mismatch problems. Is the server running x64 or x86? You are targeting which platform?

The server has appropriate .net framework installed?

Comment: @schar: run as admin . i.e. eliminate possibilities

Comment: The check for compatibility helped me solve the problem. I am yet to look at the exact cause so that I can document further. thanks

Answer (score 1):

They're throwing unhandled exceptions.  First instinct is that its a permissions problem.  Make sure the binaries aren't blocked (right click, properties, unblock button at the bottom right), then run the installer as admin.

Not sure where you got that error from, but if you haven't checked the log, do so.  If that still doesn't get you anywhere, copy the MSI installer to the 2k8 box and [follow these instructions](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/05/troubleshooting-installers.aspx) to generate a log file for the install.  May get you some add'l info.

Comment: there was no problem with the installation. It runs perfectly fine but the program failed to launch. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  Log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  That will include the exception message and a stack trace that shows you how your code got into trouble.

Comment: This helps. I got the application up and running. I am yet to investigate the exact problem though.